# Sending external messages to Telegram CLI while preserving msg_id from current session

Tags: python, bash, telegram

I am running Telegram CLI as a daemon on my localhost .

I need to forward messages from my current session while using the original msg_id .

For that matter I use the following bash command :

```
echo -e 'fwd peer msg_id' | nc.traditional -w 1 127.0.0.1 1234
```

The problem is when the command is sent it's like a new session is being opened and it can't detect the correct msg_id of the running daemon :

ANSWER 26
FAIL: 22: unknown message

How can I externally send a message to my daemon while using the msg_ids from the current session ?